# Manejo de consultas a una página web desde una aplicación de escritorio de Java

Tags: java

Debo automatizar un proceso de consultas, pero para esto la página me pide  estar identificado como usuario (logueado). Una vez me identifico desde la página web me redirecciona al formulario de consultas, pero no logro conseguir realizar las consultas desde mi aplicación de escritorio en Java (*desktop Java application*) ya que no sé cómo enviarle las cookies en la misma petición de la consulta.

Buscando por internet mencionan algo relacionado con `HTTPClient` de Apache, pero no logro hacerlo, el código que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
package commonsapache;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrador
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class CommonsApache {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {

            HttpResponse response ;
            HttpEntity entity ;

            List<Cookie> cookies ;


            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/consultas/index.php?idc=11");

            /*
             * Poner aki tus credenciales de autenticación
            */
            String usuario = "admin";
            String password = "admin";

            // Variables a mandar
            List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();

            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", usuario));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("validate", ""));

            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
            entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
//          EntityUtils.consume(entity);

            // Escribimos la respuesta de la página hacia
            //   un outputstream. En este caso: la consola.
            entity.writeTo(System.out);

            // Mostramos las cookies
            System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
            cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }

        }catch(Exception error){


        }finally {

            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

Aclaración: este código lo he conseguido tras buscar problemas similares de otras personas en Internet, pero el resultado que me genera es el siguiente:

> Login form get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> window.location.href = 'index.php?idc=37';Post logon cookies:
>
> - [version: 0][name: cookie_consultas][value: 7gsvcsee5v0ravql9hq1jujck0][domain: 127.0.0.1][path: /][expiry: null]

Según esto logré loguearme porque me realiza el re-direccionamiento al formulario de consultas pero no comprendo cómo realizar las consultas ya que la página me valida si me logueé previamente y no sé cómo enviar la cookie.

Mi pregunta concreta sería: ya que me pide que esté logueado, **¿cómo puedo usar la cookie que me retorna para poder realizar las consultas?** Es decir, en mi consulta o en lo que le envíe como petición debería ir mi cookie la cual me identifica como usuario válido.

Comment: Deberias agregar mas detalles ya que no se entiende exactamente cual es tu pregunta.

Comment: mi pregunta concreta seria, como puedo usar la cookie que me retorna  para poder realizar las consultas que me pide que este logueado, es decir en mi consulta o en lo que le envíe como petición debería ir mi cookie la cual me identifica como usuario valido, me comprendes ahora mejor o aun no me logro hacer entender ? :(

Comment: Bueno, si utilizar Apache HttpClient (imagino que la versión 3.x basado en tu código) puedes revisar su [documentación para manejo de cookies](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html). Si actualizas a Apache HttpComponents (versión 4 de esa librería, renombrada) te recomiendo ver el[tutorial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html) donde ofrecen ejemplos para trabajar con cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a ver si entendí.

Tu problema es que logras iniciar sesión (login correcto), es decir que se logra generar un sessionid; ese sessionid debe ser "reutilizable" para realizar consultas GET a recursos "privados", que sólo puedes obtener con un sessionid válido (en este caso supongo que es un form que permite realizar una búsqueda de algo).

Analicé un poco el código que muestras y creo que la cosa debería ser así:

Como estás usando `DefaultHttpClient` al realizar el primer request al servidor (POST) junto con los parámetros `username` y `password` (`validate` debe ser requerido específicamente para tu caso, supongo); si es válido el proceso de logueo entonces el objeto `httpclient` obtiene el sessionid generado durante la petición, algo como esto

```
[[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: e16beef5aa337d284c05303b0e96][domain: 10.200.200.200][path: /mysite.com][expiry: null]]
```

entonces, sabiendo esto; lo que se debe reutilizar es el objeto `httpclient` ya que es éste quien mantiene dentro del `CookieStore` los valores se sesión generados durante el login.

No veo en tu código que intentes realizar un `get` con el objeto `httpclient` luego de que confirmas que el login fué correcto:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://10.200.200.200/algo_privado.html");
//ya tiene cargado el CookieStore
response = httpclient.execute(get);
```

Para mí, el truco está en reutilizar el objeto `httpclient`, siempre validando que el proceso de login fué realizado correctamente.

Saludos!